# Room Persistence Library (Updating issue)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

**Issue:** Hello all, I'm facing an issue in Room Persistence library. I'm able to update a created row for an entity in database for first and second time but when i query to database the third time for updating the same row, its not getting updated.

**Components used:** Kotlin, Android architecture (Room Persistence Library, ViewModel) and Dagger2

**Version used:** 1.1.1

**Devices/Android versions reproduced on:** All devices

**Source Code Available at:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/nywrbpnffvb58jl/RoomDemo.zip?dl=0

Comment: give more information.

Comment: Alien, I'm updating an entity row parameter value. For the first and 2nd time, its value is being updated but after 2nd time, its neither updating the already created row value nor creating the new row for that entity.

Comment: can you please post code snippet here?

Comment: @SamirBhatt Please find source code at this link : https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112105566

Comment: @Alien you can get more information and source code at this link : https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/112105566

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code.

First, you used @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) in your Test entity.

Although you declared a test with id 0, the annonation generated the id for you. For example, first item's id is 1, and second item's is 2, etc.

Second, take a look at your TestDao.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ${Test.TABLE_NAME}")
    fun getTest(): LiveData<Test>
```

You only use one Test to get all items that you will get only first item of all tests.

Because the two problems, your second save create a test with id 2, and your getTest() always return test with id 1 which change edittext text back.